# ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' on connection

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I attempted to connect to a mysql db using mysql connector python. My table was latin encoded. I more or less tried this from the docs:

```
from mysql.connector import (connection)

cnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='scott', password='password',
                                 host='127.0.0.1',
                                 database='employees')
cnx.close()
```

But I got the error:

```
ERROR 1115 (42000): Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

Why is it finding `utf8mb4` if my table is Latin encoded?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After searching around for a while, I found this regarding connections: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html which got me thinking.

I just tried adding the `charset` argument to my connection like so:

```
cnx = connection.MySQLConnection(user='scott',
    password='password', 
    host='127.0.0.1', 
    charset='utf8', 
    database='employees')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

If your characters actually use the superset `utf8mb4` then this may cause problems, but if not, then this should work!

Answer (score 1):

Use `charset="utf8"` while creating the connection object .

```
myconn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="user", database="user_db", charset="utf8" )
```

It works for me.

Comment: How is this different from the solution I posted?